# How to Launch a PDF from a Chrome Packaged App?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, pdf, google-chrome-app

My chrome packaged app contains a PDF, and I would like to let the user view it. If I open it in the current frame I get the error "Chrome PDF Viewer is not Allowed".

Frankly, the chrome PDF viewer is pretty awful, so I'd rather let the user view it in their PDF viewer of choice anyway. If I disable the chrome PDF plugin (just as an experiment) and I try to open the PDF using chrome.app.window.open, it "downloads" the PDF, and then the user could open it. But this has two issues:

1. I can't realistically make the user go to chrome://plugins and do that disable
2. There isn't any browser window, so the user has no idea the download happened

Any suggestions? Opening PDFs that are embedded in my app is kind of a must-have feature for this app.

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried everything I could think of, but to no avail (I even tried dataURLs). Seems like Chrome Apps officialy hate PDFs. The only _"solution"_ for me was to host the file on a server and just open a browser window pointing to that file (nothing locally hosted), i.e. `window.open("http://my.domain.com/path/to/sample.pdf");`.

Comment: Thanks for trying! I can probably use that as a workaround until Chrome gets its act together. Maybe I'll call it a feature, since it means the big fat PDFs won't need to burden down the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got this working, but whether it is a solution for you depends a lot on your use case. The solution has three parts:

1. Use pdfjs to do the actual rendering.

To get this running in a packaged app, you'd need to do some violence to the internationalization support. And even after you do that, you'll find that some PDFs refuse to load for no apparent reason whatsoever. So don't bother trying to make pdfjs work in a packaged app. Just:

2. Put your entire app into a `<webview>` with a persist partition, and use a HTML5 cache manifest to get all your files available for offline viewing.

Yeah, yeah, I know that cache manifests are not cool anymore. But if you can list all your files for use in a packaged app, then you are doing the one case where cache manifests actually work great.

3. Then use a packaged app to distribute a tiny wrapper around your page with the webview in it.

You'll also get the benefit that you don't have to rewrite your app to live within the draconian packaged app rules (eval, sync xhr, 2GB limit, etc.).

You can see a working example at m.kaon.com/c/ka (visit with Chrome to get the desktop app; if you visit that with Firefox, you'll get access to a hosted app that is using the same tricks). PDFs are down in the bottom "Why Choose Kaon" section.

Answer (score 1):

I've looked at this extensively, and have come to the conclusion that there's no way to get a Chrome App to open a PDF that's local. I, too, have tried data URIs.

I don't think the issue is the PDF support in the window, as it's still Chrome, or the size of the PDFs. Rather, I think it's just an engineering problem, one that might get solved someday.

As for me, I build the PDF in my Chrome App. Since I can't display it, and there's no server to upload it to, I write it to a file of the user's choosing and let the user deal with it on his/her own.

Comment: Interesting... thanks for the tip. However, it looks like I would have to get pretty involved with the code to embed it into a Chrome App. It looks like it's set up for a Chrome Extension. Something to watch, however.

Comment: My assumption is that this limitation is intentional right now. They are hyper-paranoid about apps becoming an attack vector, and they just don't trust their own PDF rendering code enough to enable it right now. If there was a way to open a new window with a security sandbox around it, that would solve the issue, I suspect.

Comment: jesmith: See the comment from ExpertSystem, above. There's no problem accessing a PDF on a website. What you apparently can't do in a Chrome App is open a PDF that's stored locally. So, I don't think this is a PDF security issue, but rather another security issue related to local resources that impacts the ability to view local PDFs.