# Opening a mailto: link from a chrome packaged app

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I've created a chrome packaged app which comes down from the Chrome Store as a CRX. I'd like to let the user send mail from the app, using a mailto: link. It appears that this is not allowed, because of security restrictions (when I try in development, that's the error I get).

I found another thread where they said it worked by setting location.href, but that question is pretty old, and I'm assuming the security restriction may be new.

So… is there any way to open the user's local mail client from a chrome packaged app, so they can send a message?

Comment: Could you, please, post some code (because it seems to work just fine for me - in development at least).

Comment: There isn't much to it. My manifest doesn't have the sandbox thing, because I need to access the "storage" API. My main page is just a wrapper that loads my content page in an IFRAME. My content page says `location.href="mailto:blah…"`. The fact that it works for you is interesting. I wonder if I need to set window.top.location.href or something to break out of the IFRAME...

Comment: Why use `location.href=...` ? I used `<a href="mailto:...">...</a>` and it works. Did I misunderstood what you are after ?

Comment: I'll do an experiment with that. The mailto URL is generated dynamically, based on user actions, so doing it with an <a> would be a little tricky. But if it works, that would be a suitable workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few remarks:

- This question is about providing the `mailto` functionality from within an `iframe` in the main window.
- Adding a link (with the appropriate `href`) works fine, but requires user-interaction (clicking the link): `<a href="mailto:...">...</a>`
- Using `location.href = ...` is prevented from the Content Security Policy (which can possibly be relaxed - I didn't look further into it).
- Using `window.top.location.href = ...` results in the following error:
  Can't open same-window link to "mailto:..."; try target="_blank".

---

**The solution:**

It worked for me using:

```
    window.open("mailto:...");
```

---

For the sake of completeness, below is the source code of a sample extension that illustrates the above

**manifest.json:**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name":    "Test App",
    "version": "0.0",

    "app": {
        "background": {
            "scripts": ["background.js"]
        }
    }
}
```

**background.js:**

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
    chrome.app.window.create("wrapper.html");
});
```

**wrapper.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body><iframe src="main.html"></iframe></body>
</html>
```

**main.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head><script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script></head>
    <body>
        <form id="frm1">
            <input type="email" id="inp1" placeHolder="Recipient's e-mail"
                   required /><br />
            <input type="text" id="inp2" placeHolder="Message's subject"
                   required /><br />
            <input type="submit" id="btn1" value="Send e-mail" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**main.js:**

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    var frm1 = document.getElementById("frm1");
    var inp1 = document.getElementById("inp1");
    var inp2 = document.getElementById("inp2");
    var btn1 = document.getElementById("btn1");

    frm1.addEventListener("submit", function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
    });

    btn1.addEventListener("click", function() {
        var email = inp1.value;
        var subject = encodeURIComponent(inp2.value);
        var mailToStr = "mailto:" + email + "?Subject=" + subject);
        console.log(mailToStr);
        window.open(mailToStr);
    });
```

});

Comment: Using window.open worked like a champ! Note that in my case, the window needs to open after an async xmlhttp request comes back, so it's not the direct result of a user action, and it still works.

Comment: Since you nailed this question so easily, could I ask you to take a look at this one, which hasn't gotten any love:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19035195/how-to-launch-a-pdf-from-a-chrome-packaged-app